# How to find php execution time?

Tags: php, time

I have a large PHP code in my website, I want to know the **execution time** of processing. How can I do this?

```
<?php
// large code
// large code
// large code

// print execution time here
?>
```

Comment: Related: [Loading time of php page in apache server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411389/loading-time-of-php-page-in-apache-server)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can use `microtime` as the **start** and **end** of your PHP code:

```
<?php
    $time_start = microtime(true);
    sleep(1);
    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $time = $time_end - $time_start;
    echo "Process Time: {$time}";
    // Process Time: 1.0000340938568
?>
```

**As of PHP 5.4.0**, there is no need to get start time at the beginning,
the `$_SERVER` superglobal array already has it:

```
<?php
    sleep(1);
    $time = microtime(true) - $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"];
    echo "Process Time: {$time}";
    // Process Time: 1.0061590671539
?>
```

Comment: Might be worth to note that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` was available since 5.1 albeit with a precision of seconds.

Comment: +1 for the 5.4 start time superglobal

Comment: If you're measuring in seconds then your doing something wrong.

Comment: @Orangepill Thank you :) - I didn't get you on your last comment.

Comment: You don't need the curlies if you're using double quotes.