# HTTP Get time for response

Tags: php, get, guzzle

I'm playing around with guzzle and trying to build a simple page, that i can add my domains to - and have it check if they are currently online/accessible.

I can currently check if an array/list of domain's is online, or if it gets rejected for some reason. I would love to also be able to see in my log/DB how long it takes from i send a the HTTP request to [mydomain.com] until the response arrives back.

Current Code:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
use GuzzleHttp\Pool;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;

if(!empty($aDomains))
{       
    $oClient            = new Client(['expect' => false]);
    $aAcceptedResponse  = [];
    $aRejectedResponses = [];
    $aCreatedRequests    = [];
    

    foreach ($aDomains as $iDomainKey => $sDomain) 
    {          
        array_push($aCreatedRequests, new Request('GET', $sDomain));
    }

    $pool = new Pool($oClient, $aCreatedRequests, 
    [
        'concurrency' => 50,
        'options' => ['timeout' => 10],
        'fulfilled'   => function ($response, $index) use (&$aAcceptedResponse) 
        {
            $aAcceptedResponse[] = $index;
        },
        'rejected'    => function ($reason, $index) use(&$aRejectedResponses)  
        {
            $aRejectedResponses[] = $index;
        },
    ]);

    $promise = $pool->promise();
    $promise->wait();
}
```

I figured i would be able to find something in the guzzle response object, but so far i have been unable to find anything - am i blind or is it not possible to see this?

Comment: The response cannot contain such information because it is unaware of the exact moment the request had been sent. All the other side knows is when it received the request. You should measure this manually. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035859/how-to-find-php-execution-time) should get you started.

Comment: look for on_stats in docs, it has a function `getTransferTime()` will give you time check out in docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to El_Vanja's answer i figured it out by just using a global timestamp:

```
    $iStartExecutionTime = microtime(true);
    $oClient             = new Client(['expect' => false]);
    $aAcceptedResponse   = [];
    $aRejectedResponses  = [];
    $aCreatedRequests    = [];      

    foreach ($aDomains as $iDomainKey => $oDomain) 
    {          
        array_push($aCreatedRequests, new Request('GET', $oDomain->sDomainName));
        update_domain_uptime_monitor($oDomain->iID, 1, date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('NOW')+$oDomain->iInterval), date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('NOW')));
    }

    $pool = new Pool($oClient, $aCreatedRequests, 
    [
        'concurrency' => 50,
        'options' => ['timeout' => 10],
        'fulfilled'   => function ($response, $index) use (&$aAcceptedResponse) 
        {               
            $aAcceptedResponse[$index] = (microtime(true)-$GLOBALS['iStartExecutionTime']);
        },
        'rejected'    => function ($reason, $index) use(&$aRejectedResponses)  
        {
            $aRejectedResponses[] = $index;
        },
    ]);

    $promise = $pool->promise();
    $promise->wait();
```