# Does 'REQUEST_TIME' in PHP give time before DNS resolving?

Tags: php, dns

I want to know what causes the time difference between these times:

```
echo (microtime(true) - $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']).'<br>';
```

I know that `microtime(true)` gives me current time. I have doubts about `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']`. Does this tell us the time before resolving DNS or after resolving DNS? What about connection and wait time? If not that, does this variable tells us the time when first byte is received?

Comment: `microtime(true)` return current system unix timestamp, `$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"] return the time when the request starts...imo thats the time when the client send the request...meaning before DNS..how..? probably included from the header...just my guess

Answer (score 3):

The client request goes as follows:

- DNS Request to resolve server IP address
- Request to server (REQUEST_TIME starts now)
- processing of request in web service & PHP
- data sent back to client (first byte) in chunks or at once.

REQUEST_TIME is being set by the web service provider (Apache) at the start of the request. As noted by the [$_SERVER page](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) on the PHP site.

Offtopic: Using REQUEST_TIME over time() can be a resource optimization when used at the right places. This is because time() does a system request to find out the time on the server.

Also see this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411389/loading-time-of-php-page-in-apache-server) for additional information.

Edit: clarify client request process to facilitate comment

Comment: Thanks. However,  I think you misunderstood the question. What I am asking is does the start of request mean time when DNS is resoloved or time when first byte is received or something else.